# Converting more strings from serial monitor to int arrays

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, array, python

I want to transfer 8 lists from a python script, via Serial Monitor to the Arduino. I can get the strings to Arduino and Arduino saves them as String array, but I can't change it to integer (it shows as 0.00 - I then convert it to float, because I need to divide it by 10 to get back real numbers)

I changed the lat and long in the api link because of privacy. Change it to an actual value (example latitude=42.234, longitude=20.000).

Python code:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import serial
import numpy as np
import time

url = "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=xx.xxx&longitude=yy.yyy&hourly=temperature_2m&hourly=windspeed_10m&hourly=windspeed_80m&hourly=windspeed_120m&hourly=windspeed_180m&hourly=winddirection_10m&hourly=winddirection_80m&hourly=winddirection_120m&hourly=winddirection_180m"
now = datetime.now()

stavek_veter = "Vetrne karakteristike"

ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 115200)

tr_cas = int(now.strftime("%H"))-1

response = requests.get(url).json()
vremenski_podatki = response["hourly"]

temp2m = vremenski_podatki["temperature_2m"]
cas = vremenski_podatki["time"]

paket = str(ser.readline())

hitr_vetra_10m = vremenski_podatki["windspeed_10m"]
hitr_vetra_80m = vremenski_podatki["windspeed_80m"]
hitr_vetra_120m = vremenski_podatki["windspeed_120m"]
hitr_vetra_180m = vremenski_podatki["windspeed_180m"]
smer_vetra_10m = vremenski_podatki["winddirection_10m"]
smer_vetra_80m = vremenski_podatki["winddirection_80m"]
smer_vetra_120m = vremenski_podatki["winddirection_120m"]
smer_vetra_180m = vremenski_podatki["winddirection_180m"]

hitr_vetra_10m_zmn = list(np.array(hitr_vetra_10m)*10)
hitr_vetra_80m_zmn = list(np.array(hitr_vetra_80m)*10)
hitr_vetra_120m_zmn = list(np.array(hitr_vetra_120m)*10)
hitr_vetra_180m_zmn = list(np.array(hitr_vetra_180m)*10)

hitr_vetra_10m_zmn = list(map(int, hitr_vetra_10m_zmn))
hitr_vetra_80m_zmn = list(map(int, hitr_vetra_80m_zmn))
hitr_vetra_120m_zmn = list(map(int, hitr_vetra_120m_zmn))
hitr_vetra_180m_zmn = list(map(int, hitr_vetra_180m_zmn))

if stavek_veter in paket:
    time.sleep(1.7)
    ser.write((str(hitr_vetra_10m_zmn[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)]) + "\n").encode("utf-8"))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ser.write((str(hitr_vetra_80m_zmn[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n").encode("utf-8"))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ser.write((str(hitr_vetra_120m_zmn[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n").encode("utf-8"))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ser.write((str(hitr_vetra_180m_zmn[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n").encode("utf-8"))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ser.write((str(smer_vetra_10m[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n").encode("utf-8"))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ser.write((str(smer_vetra_80m[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n").encode("utf-8"))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ser.write((str(smer_vetra_120m[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n").encode("utf-8"))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    ser.write((str(smer_vetra_180m[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n").encode("utf-8"))
    time.sleep(0.5)

print("Cas ob rezultatih: \n")
print(str(cas[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n")
print("Hitrost vetra 10m \n")
print(str(hitr_vetra_10m[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n")
print("Hitrost vetra 80m \n")
print(str(hitr_vetra_80m[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n")
print("Hitrost vetra 120m \n")
print(str(hitr_vetra_120m[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n")
print("Hitrost vetra 180m \n")
print(str(hitr_vetra_180m[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n")
print("Smer vetra 10m \n")
print(str(smer_vetra_10m[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n")
print("Smer vetra 80m \n")
print(str(smer_vetra_80m[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n")
print("Smer vetra 120m \n")
print(str(smer_vetra_120m[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n")
print("Smer vetra 180m \n")
print(str(smer_vetra_180m[tr_cas: (tr_cas+6)])+ "\n")

while True:
    paket = str(ser.readline())
    print(paket.encode("utf"))
```

Arduino code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
//#include <WireIMXRT.h>
//#include <WireKinetis.h>

int hitr_vetra_10m[6], hitr_vetra_120m[6], hitr_vetra_80m[6], hitr_vetra_180m[6];
int smer_vetra_10m[6], smer_vetra_80m[6],smer_vetra_120m[6], smer_vetra_180m[6];
float hitr_vetra_10m_ko[6], hitr_vetra_120m_ko[6], hitr_vetra_80m_ko[6], hitr_vetra_180m_ko[6];

int n, k;


String ser_string[8];

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  delay(6000);
  
  Serial.println("Vetrne karakteristike");
  delay(2000);

  for(n = 0; n<=8; n++){
    if(Serial.available()>=14){
      ser_string[n] = Serial.readStringUntil("\n");
      Serial.flush();
      Serial.println(ser_string[n]);

      if(n==0){
        while(ser_string[n].indexOf(",")!=-1){
          hitr_vetra_10m[k] = ser_string[n].substring(0,ser_string[n].indexOf(",")).toInt();
          k++;    
        }
        hitr_vetra_10m[k]=ser_string[n].toInt();
      }

      k=0;
      if(n==1){
        while(ser_string[n].indexOf(",")!=-1){
          hitr_vetra_80m[k] = ser_string[n].substring(0,ser_string[n].indexOf(",")).toInt();
          k++;    
        }
        hitr_vetra_80m[k]=ser_string[n].toInt();
      }
      k=0;

      if(n==2){
        while(ser_string[n].indexOf(",")!=-1){
          hitr_vetra_120m[k] = ser_string[n].substring(0,ser_string[n].indexOf(",")).toInt();
          k++;    
        }
        hitr_vetra_120m[k]=ser_string[n].toInt();
      }
      k=0;

      if(n==3){
        while(ser_string[n].indexOf(",")!=-1){
          hitr_vetra_180m[k] = ser_string[n].substring(0,ser_string[n].indexOf(",")).toInt();
          k++;    
        }
        hitr_vetra_180m[k]=ser_string[n].toInt();
      }
      k=0;

      if(n==4){
        while(ser_string[n].indexOf(",")!=-1){
          smer_vetra_10m[k] = ser_string[n].substring(0,ser_string[n].indexOf(",")).toInt();
          k++;    
        }
        smer_vetra_10m[k]=ser_string[n].toInt();
      }
      k=0;

      if(n==5){
        while(ser_string[n].indexOf(",")!=-1){
          smer_vetra_80m[k] = ser_string[n].substring(0,ser_string[n].indexOf(",")).toInt();
          k++;    
        }
        smer_vetra_80m[k]=ser_string[n].toInt();
      } 
      k=0;       

      if(n==6){
        while(ser_string[n].indexOf(",")!=-1){
          smer_vetra_120m[k] = ser_string[n].substring(0,ser_string[n].indexOf(",")).toInt();
          k++;    
        }
        smer_vetra_120m[k]=ser_string[n].toInt();
      }
      k=0;

      if(n==7){
        while(ser_string[n].indexOf(",")!=-1){
          smer_vetra_180m[k] = ser_string[n].substring(0,ser_string[n].indexOf(",")).toInt();
          k++;    
        }
        smer_vetra_180m[k]=ser_string[n].toInt();
      }  
      k=0;  

      delay(500);
    }
    
  }
  n=0;

  for(int b = 0; b<=5;b++){
    hitr_vetra_10m_ko[b]=hitr_vetra_10m[b]/10.0;
    hitr_vetra_80m_ko[b]=hitr_vetra_80m[b]/10.0;
    hitr_vetra_120m_ko[b]=hitr_vetra_120m[b]/10.0;
    hitr_vetra_180m_ko[b]=hitr_vetra_180m[b]/10.0;
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  for(int j = 0; j<=5; j++){
    Serial.println(hitr_vetra_10m_ko[j]);
  }
  delay(5000);

}
```

Why does it only write out 0.0 for every place in the array (example: [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]?

Thanks in advance for all help.

EDIT:

I've changed the last part of python code to this

```
while True:
    paket = str(ser.readline().decode("utf"))
    print(paket.encode("ASCII"))
```

and I get the following result when I print what is coming from Serial monitor (whatever data I print in python and the show it in VScode terminal.)

```
Cas ob rezultatih: 

['2023-02-13T18:00', '2023-02-13T19:00', '2023-02-13T20:00', '2023-02-13T21:00', '2023-02-13T22:00', '2023-02-13T23:00']

Hitrost vetra 10m 

[2.1, 3.1, 1.3, 1.9, 2.3, 2.6]

Hitrost vetra 80m 

[0.4, 1.1, 2.5, 0.5, 1.8, 1.8]

Hitrost vetra 120m 

[0.7, 0.7, 3.3, 1.1, 1.0, 1.8]

Hitrost vetra 180m

[1.3, 1.0, 4.0, 2.5, 0.8, 0.4]

Smer vetra 10m

[211, 249, 146, 248, 219, 214]

Smer vetra 80m

[360, 252, 98, 225, 217, 217]

Smer vetra 120m

[360, 180, 84, 90, 225, 217]

Smer vetra 180m

[34, 135, 85, 90, 63, 180]

b'[21,31,13,19,23,26]\n'
b'[4,11,25,5,18,18]\n'
b'[7,7,33,11,10,18]\n'
b'[13,10,40,25,8,4]\n'
b'[211,249,146,248,219,214]\n'
b'[360,252,98,225,217,217]\n'
b'[360,180,84,90,225,217]\n'
b'[34,135,85,90,63,180]\n'
b'\r\n'
b'[21,31,13,19,23,26]\n'
b'[4,11,25,5,18,18]\n'
b'[7,7,33,11,10,18]\n'
b'[13,10,40,25,8,4]\n'
b'[211,249,146,248,219,214]\n'
b'[360,252,98,225,217,217]\n'
b'[360,180,84,90,225,217]\n'
b'[34,135,85,90,63,180]\n'
b'\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'[21,31,13,19,23,26]\n'
b'[4,11,25,5,18,18]\n'
b'[7,7,33,11,10,18]\n'
b'[13,10,40,25,8,4]\n'
b'[211,249,146,248,219,214]\n'
b'[360,252,98,225,217,217]\n'
b'[360,180,84,90,225,217]\n'
b'[34,135,85,90,63,180]\n'
b'\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'\r\n'
b'\r\n'
```

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: For debugging, first change your python encoding to `encode('ASCII')` instead of `encode('utf8')` (BTW, your `paket.encode("utf")` doesn't seems to be correct. If you need other to help you, an example of what the data been sent by phthon code, and what you have received by the Arduino would be helpful to understand what exactly the problem you are facing.

Comment: @hcheung I've edited the post and added soma data.

Comment: Okay, if your `Hitrost vetra 10m` is a String representative of  floating point as `[2.1, 3.1, 1.3, 1.9, 2.3, 2.6]`, you need to parse it with `hitr_vetra_80m[k]=ser_string[n].toFloat();` instead of using `toInt()` method. See more about [toFloat()] method at [toFloat()](https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/cs/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/tofloat/).

Comment: @hcheung I've multiplied the numbers by 10 and will then divide it by 10 in the Arduino, so I don't read floats from Serial monitor because I've read it's very difficult to read floats.